# QLineEdit not setting Text in QT?

Tags: qt

I am using a QtLine Edit and setting some text to it using lineEdit->settext("Test").
This works fine but when i set data from my Structure and convert it from Wide Char array it does not set it.

```
lineEdit->setText(QString::fromWCharArray(pUserInfo.LastName,MAX_NAME_SIZE));
```

pUserInfo is a structure 
Last Name is of Type wchar_t ,LastName[MAX_NAME_SIZE];

I resolved it using

```
 QString::fromWCharArray(pUserInfo.FirstName,wcslen(pUserInfo.FirstName));
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the comma a copy paste error?  wchar_t ,Last_N...

Comment: Shouldn't it be MAX_NAME_SIZE-1? Is your string null-terminated?

Comment: @frank : how to make it null terminated ?

Comment: What is the content of LastName then (in hex)? How can you tell the actual length of the string if it is not null-terminated? In case there is no \0 but random data, the conversion might break due to invalid bytes.

Comment: Probably the setText is not the problem.. Try `QString test = QString::fromWCharArray(pUserInfo.LastName,MAX_NAME_SIZE));` and then `qDebug() << test` (you will have to `#include <QtCore/QDebug>`). And see if the `test` string even has content.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it using

```
QString::fromWCharArray(pUserInfo.FirstName,wcslen(pUserInfo.FirstName));
```